# Distributing app to App Store Connect upload fails with invalid NSExtention key error in info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, info.plist, remote-notifications

I'm trying to upload an app to use Test Flight to test it. All goes well until the actual upload when it fails with the error:

```
Distribution failed with errors:   
App Store Connect Operation Error invalid Info.plist Key.  The key 'NSExtension' in the Info.plist file is not valid. With error code
    STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90190 for id...'
```

I also get:

```
Distribution failed with errors:
App Store Connect Operation Error
ERROR ITMS-90190: "Invalid Info.plist Key. The key 'NSExtension' in the Info.plist file is not valid."
```

The pertinent section of the Info.plist is:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionCategory</key>
        <string>actionCategory</string>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionDefaultContentHidden</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionInitialContentSizeRatio</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.usernotifications.content-extension</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).NotificationService</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I know that the NSExtensionMainStoryboard and NSExtensionPrincipalClass keys are mutually exclusive.  I've tried submitting with just one or the other key included and received the same result.

I've checked this as best I can with Apple docs and I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your **app's** `Info.plist` have an `NSExtension` key?  Only your extension's `Info.plist` should contain the `NSExtension` attributes.

Comment: Yes!  The extension does have its own info.plist.  I removed the NSExtension keys from the app's Info.plist and the archive successfully uploaded to App Store Connect.  Thank-you so much!